# how to show the linux font name

Tags: terminal, fonts

I want to check the font name in linux, so I use this commnad:

```
/app # fc-list :lang=zh-tw|grep "標楷體"
/usr/share/fonts/zh/tw/標楷體.ttf: AR PL KaitiM Big5,文鼎ＰＬ中楷:style=Regular
```

does the file `標楷體.ttf` font name is `AR PL KaitiM Big5`? what shoud I do to show the real name of the font?

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the output of my system and some known fonts:

```
$ fc-list | grep -E '(Arial|Roman):'
/usr/share/fonts/gsfonts/NimbusRoman-Bold.otf: Nimbus Roman:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Times.TTF: Times New Roman:style=Regular,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Standaard,Normalny,Обычный,Normálne,Navadno,thường,Arrunta
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Arialbd.TTF: Arial:style=Bold,Negreta,tučné,fed,Fett,Έντονα,Negrita,Lihavoitu,Gras,Félkövér,Grassetto,Vet,Halvfet,Pogrubiony,Negrito,Полужирный,Fet,Kalın,Krepko,đậm,Lodia
/usr/share/fonts/gsfonts/NimbusRoman-BoldItalic.otf: Nimbus Roman:style=Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Arialbi.TTF: Arial:style=Bold Italic,Negreta cursiva,tučné kurzíva,fed kursiv,Fett Kursiv,Έντονα Πλάγια,Negrita Cursiva,Lihavoitu Kursivoi,Gras Italique,Félkövér dőlt,Grassetto Corsivo,Vet Cursief,Halvfet Kursiv,Pogrubiona kursywa,Negrito Itálico,Полужирный Курсив,Tučná kurzíva,Fet Kursiv,Kalın İtalik,Krepko poševno,nghiêng đậm,Lodi etzana
/usr/share/fonts/gsfonts/NimbusRoman-Regular.otf: Nimbus Roman:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/gsfonts/NimbusRoman-Italic.otf: Nimbus Roman:style=Italic
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Ariali.TTF: Arial:style=Italic,Cursiva,kurzíva,kursiv,Πλάγια,Kursivoitu,Italique,Dőlt,Corsivo,Cursief,Kursywa,Itálico,Курсив,İtalik,Poševno,nghiêng,Etzana
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Timesi.TTF: Times New Roman:style=Italic,cursiva,kurzíva,kursiv,Πλάγια,Kursivoitu,Italique,Dőlt,Corsivo,Cursief,kursywa,Itálico,Курсив,İtalik,Poševno,nghiêng,Etzana
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Timesbd.TTF: Times New Roman:style=Bold,Negreta,tučné,fed,Fett,Έντονα,Negrita,Lihavoitu,Gras,Félkövér,Grassetto,Vet,Halvfet,Pogrubiona,Negrito,Полужирный,Fet,Kalın,Krepko,đậm,Lodia
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Timesbi.TTF: Times New Roman:style=Bold Italic,Negreta cursiva,tučné kurzíva,fed kursiv,Fett Kursiv,Έντονα Πλάγια,Negrita Cursiva,Lihavoitu Kursivoi,Gras Italique,Félkövér dőlt,Grassetto Corsivo,Vet Cursief,Halvfet Kursiv,Pogrubiona kursywa,Negrito Itálico,Полужирный Курсив,Tučná kurzíva,Fet Kursiv,Kalın İtalik,Krepko poševno,nghiêng đậm,Lodi etzana
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Arial.TTF: Arial:style=Regular,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Standaard,Normalny,Обычный,Normálne,Navadno,thường,Arrunta
```

Based on that, it appears that the "name", what we are used to seeing the font called, is the second `:`-defined field. So you can get the name with:

```
$ fc-list | grep -E '(Arial|Roman):' | cut -d: -f 2
 Nimbus Roman
 Times New Roman
 Arial
 Nimbus Roman
 Arial
 Nimbus Roman
 Nimbus Roman
 Arial
 Times New Roman
 Times New Roman
 Times New Roman
 Arial
```

For your font, that would return `AR PL KaitiM Big5,文鼎ＰＬ中楷`, so I guess that is the name of your font.